# How to scroll to bottom of div using Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the names of all the guests attending my event and have selected 'going' on my event.

I go to the event page, click on the `X going / Y interested` option and a dialog box opens. The dialog box can be scrolled and has to be scrolled to get the list of all the guests of my events. It is a typical scrollable window with lazy loading.

I have tried using `execute_script` function to scroll down a little but since I don't know enough javascript, I could not modify it to reach the end of the dialog box.

How can I scroll to the end of the dialog box?

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS 3.2_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use [**`Facebook Graph API`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the element `id` you can use this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.sl.find_element_by_id('my-id')).perform()
```

Comment: Since the dialog box has to be loaded each time to reach the end, I do not know at the beginning of my script where I need to stop. So using your method will not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Have tried the below options.Try this with your div_element.

```
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", div_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used zooming out for my dynamic content. Elements get small and you get to fetch 'em all.

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='zoom %'")
```